# ADB - No connected devices (RuntimeError)

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb, calabash

I am trying to test the behaviour of my app when the device temporary loses connection.

Obviously I would like to automate this test without having to manually switch on and off the AIRPLANE MODE or Enabling / disabling the data access.

I am using calabash-android connecting to an emulator.
(cannot run the following commands on a real device for they will raise Permission issues. AIRPLANE_MODE is a protected intent therefore can only be sent by the system)

when I run the following commands:

```
adb shell settings put global airplane_mode_on 1
adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE
```

The emulator switches to airplane mode as expected but at this point something happens...
ADB loses the visibility of the device and consequently calabash-android starts to complain as follow:

```
 Connection refused - connect(2) (http://127.0.0.1:34778) (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
  bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/httpclient-2.3.4.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:803:in `initialize'
  bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/httpclient-2.3.4.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:803:in `new'
  bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/httpclient-2.3.4.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:803:in `create_socket'
  bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/httpclient-2.3.4.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:752:in `block in connect'
  bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/httpclient-2.3.4.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:751:in `connect'
  bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/httpclient-2.3.4.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:609:in `query'
  bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/httpclient-2.3.4.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:164:in `query'
  bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/httpclient-2.3.4.1/lib/httpclient.rb:1083:in `do_get_block'
  bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/httpclient-2.3.4.1/lib/httpclient.rb:887:in `block in do_request'
  bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/httpclient-2.3.4.1/lib/httpclient.rb:981:in `protect_keep_alive_disconnected'
  bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/httpclient-2.3.4.1/lib/httpclient.rb:886:in `do_request'
  bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/httpclient-2.3.4.1/lib/httpclient.rb:774:in `request'
  bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/httpclient-2.3.4.1/lib/httpclient.rb:684:in `post'
  bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/calabash-android-0.4.16/lib/calabash-android/operations.rb:334:in `make_http_request'
  bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/calabash-android-0.4.16/lib/calabash-android/operations.rb:294:in `http'
  bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/calabash-android-0.4.16/lib/calabash-android/operations.rb:556:in `shutdown_test_server'
  bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/calabash-android-0.4.16/lib/calabash-android/operations.rb:97:in `shutdown_test_server'
  /scratch/git/we7-Android/Main/features/support/app_life_cycle_hooks.rb:49:in `After'
```

Any suggestions? please help

Comment: You *do* know that airplane mode kills all connectivity, right? It does exactly what you ask it to.

Comment: Perhaps you should consider shutting down the hosting system's network access instead.  Or configuring some soft firewall around the emulator.

Comment: Hi Chris, that is exactly what I am trying to do at the moment. Good suggestion, thanks.